# Javascript para deletar

Tags: javascript

Não tenho conhecimento em jv, porém vi que é com essa linguagem que da pra usar scripts e apagar itens de redes sociais como por exp no twitter:

```
setInterval(function(){t=$(".following").find(".follow-button");if(!t[0]){window.scrollTo(0,$(document).height());}else{ console.log(t.attr("class")); t.trigger("click");}},10)
```

Gostaria de saber / ajuda com um script para apagar os likes e comentários feitos no facebook por essa página : fb.com/usuario-aqui/allactivity

Answer (score 2):

Não, ele não pode apagar as coisas dos sites e redes sociais. O que você ve na tela é, na verdade, uma manipulação do que já está baixado no seu computador.

Você até pode deletar e mudar a quantidade de likes, aumentar o número de notificações, mas assim que você recarregar a página, tudo vai voltar como era antes, porque o JS roda no seu browser e apenas dentro dele, tudo que for feito vai ser persistido somente durante sua própria sessão.